# Flutter: We've detected that your app contains the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag in the manifest file of 1 or more of your app bundles or APKs

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play

I have an app on Google play store that uses the Flutter image_picker. I have received an alert from Google which says that I cannot use requestLegacyExternalStorage =true in my manifest file. I am confused and don't know what to do because in the documentation of image_picker it clearly says that we should use requestLegacyExternalStorage in the manifest file. Please help me solve this problem and is there a workaround for this?

[image]

Comment: You need to either remove that module from your app or hope for an update that doesn't `requestLegacyExternalStorage`. That flag will still be functional (when your app is ran on devices running android 10), it's just new googles policy not to accept apps that use it on their store.

Comment: does this means that my app will be removed from the playstore after 5th may ?

Comment: From what I understand may 5th is when "permission declaration form" will become accessible so they shouldn't be removing apps for a while.

Comment: okay thank you soo much for a fast replay

Comment: The conclusion we've come to on [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/mqzls8/ominous_scoped_storage_warning_messages/) is that, your app won't be affected in any way for using requestLegacyExternalStorage. So you can simply ignore this unnecessarily-confusing announcement.

Comment: @Pawel In my apps I have targetsdk as 29 & requestLegacyExternalStorage is true. I got same notice for my apps & worried shall i remove that flag from manifest? Impact will be on android 10 devices as for android 11 scoped storage is used.

Answer (score 1):

If your `targetSdk` is not 30 you can keep using the flag `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` and you don't have to do anything.

From [this post](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955?hl=en):

> Google Play restricts the use of [high risk or sensitive
> permissions](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/),
> including a special app access called [All files
> access](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage#all-files-access).
> This is only applicable to apps that target Android 11 (API level 30)
> and declare the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, which is added
> in Android 11. Also, this policy does not impact the usage of the
> `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.
>
> If your app does not require access to the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
> permission, you must remove it from your app's manifest in order to
> successfully publish your app. Details on policy-compliant alternative
> implementations are also detailed below.
>
> If your app meets the policy requirements for acceptable use or is
> eligible for an exception, you will be required to [declare this and
> any other high risk
> permissions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102)
> using the Declaration Form in Play Console.
>
> Apps that fail to meet policy requirements or do not submit a
> Declaration Form may be removed from Google Play.

Also, [this GitHub post](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12603) have a good discussion about this:

> SDK 41 contains all the necessary changes to make your app compatible
> with Android 11, and should not result in removal from the Play Store.
> There is no action for you to take. Just because you received this
> warning, does not mean your app is infringing on the new scoped
> storage policy. According to [this
> response](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/mwaqn1/scoped_storage_recap/gw1fext/?%24deep_link=true&correlation_id=edc3b9e9-8a12-4213-8d05-822b15eb755f&ref=email_comment_reply&ref_campaign=email_comment_reply&ref_source=email&%243p=e_as&_branch_match_id=765301748601551842)
> from someone at Google, they sent this warning to anyone using the
> `requestLegacyExternalStorage` flag since it is their best indicator
> of apps that may need to declare the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
> permission.
>
> - If you're on SDK 41- you have nothing to do, you can ignore this warning.
> - If you're on SDK 40 or below- you can ignore this warning since it's specific to targeting Android 11.

Check out also this useful links:

- https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage
- https://www.androidcentral.com/what-scoped-storage